# Wordpress Custom Taxonomy URL Hierarchy

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a custom taxonomy that is set to Hierarchical = true. However, when I try to access them hierarchically in the URL, it doesn't work.

i.e.

```
| Training (Taxonomy Name)
| - test-taxonomy
| - - another-test-taxonomy
```

My expected URL would be mysite.com/training/test-taxonomy/another-test-taxonomy/. That gives a Page Not Found error though.

I can access both `test-taxonomy` and `another-test-taxonomy` like so: `mysite.com/training/<slug>`, but it doesn't seem to work hierarchically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/hierarchical-custom-taxonomy-permalinks

Here's the trac ticket: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12659

Unfortunately, the bottom line is it can't be done without some serious hacking right now - ran into the same problem a few weeks ago. Likely in near future releases, I would think.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for the info, Gavin.

Answer (score 0):

11 years late, but I just found the solution to this problem in Gavin's link: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/hierarchical-custom-taxonomy-permalinks/#post-1520946

To implement the solution, in my call to `register_taxonomy`, I changed the

```
'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => 'training'
)
```

part to

```
'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => 'training',
    'hierarchical' => true
)
```

I then went into my **Permalink Settings** page ( https://example.org/wp-admin/options-permalink.php ) and just clicked the **Saved Changes** button and, having it large, the URLs of my hierarchical custom taxonomy are now also hierarchical - and they work on every level!! Sorted.